# UWP (C#) - Getting result of PermissionRequest

Tags: c#, geolocation, win-universal-app

how can I check if user allows or not the PermissionRequest for my WebView which needs to use user's position. The line with my message dialog isn't reached after user click "Deny".

```
private async void webView_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PermissionRequest.PermissionType == WebViewPermissionType.Geolocation)
        args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
    else
        await new MessageDialog("Geolocation services must be allowed for this app. Please check your settings.").ShowAsync();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the `WebViewPermissionRequest.State` to determine that user have grant the permission or not. Use `args.State`.

this line

```
if (args.PermissionRequest.PermissionType == WebViewPermissionType.Geolocation)
```

only check the **type** of the requested permission. It have nothing to do with if user granted the permission before or not.

Comment: Then the event which shows prompt to user is this: `args.PermissionRequest.Allow();`?

Comment: if(args.State != WebViewPermissionState.Allow) args.PermissionRequest.Allow();